# Can I transfer vertex or weight paint of a mesh to Unreal cloth painting? (APX)

Tags: game-engine

I have a very complex model for Unreal Engine cloth simulation. It's really hard to do cloth painting on it. And Also If I change the shape or number of vertex of the mesh, It need to be repainted. It's too complicate. Is there any way to transfer the weight or vertex color paint from blender to export or transfer them into APX cloth painting?

Comment: I've seen an addon that claims to have some functionality for this, but I haven't tried it myself: http://mosthostla.com/gamedev/bonebreaker/

Comment: thank you. that was big help!